How is this question about barbell materials for outdoors opinion-based?
Of course "what's the best" type of questions will usually have answers based on opinions, but this question asks about which materials are best for outdoor equipment. Isn't the answer objectively whichever materials resist to corrosion and can stand weather conditions, based on materials science and engineering?

The issue with how the question is written is that it does not define what “best” means. Sure, we can talk about what materials have the best corrosion resistance, and that may be what makes equipment “best” to you and I, but OP hasn’t explained what “best” means for their question.

I see the new edits / reopen, but the question was "best for outdoors". That implies "weather conditions" which are usually: water, UV and dirt / sand. I get if the question was just "which material is the best".
